# Related youtube videos showing although REL=0

Tags: youtube

I created a small youtube gallery. Clicking on one of the thumbnails plays the video in the main DIV. Although I have set REL=0 in the youtube iframe source, the related videos are still showing. Any ideas why this is happening?
This is a page where the issue is happening:
https://www.itaysharf.com/%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%AA/

HTML and JS code:

```js
$(".video_wrapper li").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#bigvid").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});

 $(".video_wrapper").on('click',"a", function(event) {
 
 
  
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.stopPropagation();
 
 $(".video_case iframe").prop("src", $(event.currentTarget).attr("href"));
 


});
```

```html
    <div class="video_case" id="bigvid">
    <iframe width="705" height="445" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php the_field('main-video'); ?>&#63rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay"></iframe>
  <span class="desc">  <?php the_field('video-desc'); ?></span>
</div>

<?php if (get_field('video-id-1')): ?>
<div class="video_wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li class="video_thumbnail"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php the_field('video-id-1'); ?>&#63rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" class="video-1" title=""><span class="video-btn"></span><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php the_field('video-id-1'); ?>/mqdefault.jpg" alt="<?php the_field('video-alt-1'); ?>"/></a></li>
        <li class="video_thumbnail"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php the_field('video-id-2'); ?>&#63rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" class="video-2" title=""><span class="video-btn"></span><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php the_field('video-id-2'); ?>/mqdefault.jpg" alt="<?php the_field('video-alt-2'); ?>"/></a></li>
        <li class="video_thumbnail"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php the_field('video-id-3'); ?>&#63rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" class="video-3" title=""><span class="video-btn"></span><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php the_field('video-id-3'); ?>/mqdefault.jpg" alt="<?php the_field('video-alt-3'); ?>"/></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks for your help
Dan

Comment: Take a look at your embeds. You've got `&#63` where you should have a `?`.

Comment: That is  unicode for the question mark. When looking at the live site, it outputs correctly ?rel=0, similar to the &amp which is unicode for the '&' symbol

Comment: I believe there should at least be a `;` at the end. That said, looks like you're right it's not the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018

> The behavior for the rel parameter is changing on or after September 25, 2018. The effect of the change is that you will not be able to disable related videos. However, you will have the option of specifying that the related videos shown in the player should be from the same channel as the video that was just played.

Comment: wow, this is huge. Didn't realize this.
So I guess there is no way to bypass this? Thanks

Comment: I would assume there's no way to bypass this. Kinda shitty of YouTube, really.